WordPress category pagination wrong count
I'm having some trouble with counting the subcategories for my pagination. No matter what number I include for $cats_per_page I always see 10 page buttons (the ones with content plus empty pages until page 10).
The objective is to display all subcategories of the first category and have a pagination based on how many subcategories I have (so not posts). Only the pagination count part is not working as it shows more pages than it should. My guess is that the issue is in the $cat_count but I have no idea what's wrong. Any help is appreciated.
EDIT: added a simpler way of counting all subcategories. Both $cat_count and $max_num_pages give the right values but the pagination still shows extra numbers (empty pages).
    $taxonomy   = 'category';
    
    //count all subcategories of category ID 1
        $argscnt = array('parent' => 1);
        $cat_count = count(get_categories( $argscnt ));
        
    //How many subcategories per page                   
        $cats_per_page = 8;
    
    //get the total number of pages
        $max_num_pages = ceil( $cat_count/$cats_per_page );
        $current_page = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1; // Change to 'page' for static front page
        $offset       = ( $cats_per_page * $current_page ) - $cats_per_page;
        
$cats        = get_terms(
          [
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
             'order'    => 'DESC',
             'child_of'=>1,
             'orderby'    => 'count',
             'number'   => $cats_per_page,
             'offset'   => $offset
          ]
        );
                
                foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                //THE SUBCAT CONTENT
                }
            
            //The pagination
            
             the_posts_pagination( array(
                'mid_size'  => 2,
                'prev_text' => __( 'Back', 'textdomain' ),
                'next_text' => __( 'Onward', 'textdomain' ),
            ) );


The pagination functions don't magically know how many result pages you actually have, you need to tell them. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/#parameters - you need to at least specify `total``

But isn't $max_num_pages for that? If so it's already there.

I found the solution by adding this line 'total' => ceil( $cat_count/$cats_per_page ) inside the pagination itself. So there's no need for $max_num_pages as shown in my code above. Hope this helps someone.
the_posts_pagination( array(
   'mid_size'  => 2,
    'prev_text' => __( 'Back', 'textdomain' ),
    'next_text' => __( 'Onward', 'textdomain' ),
    'total' => ceil( $cat_count/$cats_per_page ),
 ) );

            
            

